# Editing and saving xlsx with NPOI results in a corrupted file

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, npoi

```
FileStream s = new FileStream(@myPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
IWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(s);
s.Close();

ISheet isheet = wb.GetSheetAt(0);
IRow irow = isheet.CreateRow(0);
irow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("foo");

s = new FileStream(@myPath + "blah.xlsx", FileMode.Create);
wb.Write(s);
s.Close();
```

New file is created but corrupted. I've seen people say this is fixed in version 2.0.6, but still not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using @myPath as the share / file name on line 1 of your code to create a Stream, yet you concatenate a file name onto @myPath to save the file.  Could this be the source of the error?

Comment: If I don't concatenate, it just overwrites with the same problem persisting. The problem was with SharpLibZip's Zip64 format. If you manually unzip and rezip the corrupted xlsx file, it works. Or you could turn off Zip64 in your code. https://npoi.codeplex.com/workitem/12847

Comment: I can confirm the findings of @DenisD, with the version 2.1.3.1 of NPOI: When I manually unzip and re-zip the file, MS Excel 2013 is happy.